# Singly Linked List with Header - ERROR

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to implement queues with linked list with header node. The program is compiling , but it is giving run time error. Can you please suggest what should I change?

Display function is fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MALLOC(p,n,type)        \
p=(type*)malloc(n*sizeof(type));    \

struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *link;
};
typedef struct node *NODE;

NODE insert_rear(int item,NODE head)
{

NODE temp;
MALLOC(temp,1,struct node);
temp->info=item;
temp->link=NULL;
if(head==NULL)
{
    head->link=temp;
    return head;

}
NODE cur;

while(cur->link!=NULL)
{
    cur=cur->link;
}
cur->link=temp;

return head;
}

NODE delete_front(NODE head)
{
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty");
        return head;

    }
    NODE temp,first;
    first=head->link;
    head->link=first->link;
    printf("Item deleted is %d",first->info);
    free(first);


    return head;
}
```

Comment: What kind of run-time error?  Errors come in different types.

Comment: You don't have a program here that we can run, specifically because it is lacking a `main` function.   I cannot compile and run this code, so I cannot reproduce your problem, so I cannot help you.

Comment: Remove the semicolon at the end of the `#define` line.  And remove at least the second backslash; the whole macro would fit on one line comfortably, so I'd lose both.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler:  100% correct, and macro parameters should be protected by parens, and there is no point in this macro anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

Does this line make any sense to you?

```
if(head==NULL)
{
    head->link=temp;
```

Rephrased, if `head` is NULL, go ahead and dereference a ***known*** invalid pointer.
Of course you'll get a seg-fault!

---

**PS**
I found this by writing a `main` function, and most importantly, tracing the code in a debugger.
You MUST trace your code in a debugger.

The `main` I used:

```
int main ()
{
    NODE head = NULL;
    head = insert_rear(3, head);  // <= Breakpoint here.  Step Into

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```